# Find the limit $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n^2 \int_0^{2n} e^{-n|x-n|}\log\left[1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right] dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n^2 \int_0^{2n} e^{-n|x-n|}\log\bigg[1+\frac{1}{x+1}\bigg] dx$$

I tried to change the variable $y=n(x-n)$, then we get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n \int_{-n^2}^{n^2} e^{-|y|}\log\bigg[1+\frac{1}{1+n+\frac{y}{n}}\bigg] dy$$ But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Do you have the dominated convergence theorem at your disposal?

Comment: DCT can be used, but I failed to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-n \leqslant y \leqslant n^2$, we have

$$1 + n + \frac{y}{n} \geqslant n$$

and therefore

$$n\log \left[1 + \frac{1}{1+n+\frac{y}{n}}\right] \leqslant n \log \left[ 1+\frac{1}{n}\right] < 1.$$

Thus we can use the dominated convergence theorem in a standard way to compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_{-n}^{n^2} e^{-\lvert y\rvert} \log \left[ 1+ \frac{1}{1+n+\frac{y}{n}}\right]\,dy.$$

It remains to consider

$$n\int_{-n^2}^{-n} e^{-\lvert y\rvert} \log \left[1+\frac{1}{1+n+\frac{y}{n}}\right]\,dy.$$

Note that $n \leqslant \lvert y\rvert$ there. That gives you another integrable dominating function, and the dominated convergence theorem again yields the limit.